# Meet condition from multiple text values in nodelist of a querySelectorAll

Tags: javascript

I have a nodelist with innerText. I am converting the innerText to an array.

Screen-shot of the nodelist:

[image: Screen-shot of the nodelist]

Below is my code:

```
var fltarr = []
for( z=0; z<document.querySelectorAll("div.flight-number").length; z++){
fltarr.push(document.querySelectorAll("div.flight-number")[z].innerText)
}
```

Now I am creating the `if` conditions as below but instead of using or || statement, is there another way to use for example coma separated etc to keep the code cleaner and not to clutter with too many ||.

[image: Conditions for fltarr]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try with [`Array.prototype.some()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some)

```js
var flatarr= Array.from(document.querySelectorAll("div.flight-number")).map(el => el.textContent);
console.log(flatarr.some(i => ['NH 96', 'NH 98'].includes(i)))
// BY USING REGEX
console.log(flatarr.some(i => i.match(/^NH\s9[8|6]$/g)))
```

```html
<div class="flight-number">NH 96</div>
<div class="flight-number">EY 871</div>
<div class="flight-number">NH 97</div>
```

For every match, try using [`Array.prototype.every()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every)

Answer (score 0):

You mean

```
[...document.querySelectorAll("div.flight-number")]
  .filter(div => ["NH 98","NH 96"].includes(div.textContent.trim())
```

Easier to answer if you post actual HTML and what you want as output

Here are all the divs content

```
[...document.querySelectorAll("div.flight-number")]
  .map(div => div.textContent.trim())
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create an array of values you & use [every](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every) to check if the values exist like this

```
var valuesToCheck = ['NH 96', 'NH 98']
flatarr.every(i => valuesToCheck.includes(i))
```